# Heroku No such app error with Node.js node-http-proxy module

Tags: node.js, proxy, heroku, http-proxy

I'm trying to redirect traffic from my test app's /api/* url to my api hosted on Heroku.

Therefore, localhost/api/hello
should be proxied to testapp.heroku.com/hello
and the response returned.

Using node-http-proxy works perfectly on localhost to localhost, but when I point it to myapp.heroku.com, I get this error:

```
Heroku | No such app
There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.
```

I have a feeling it's Heroku's routing system that's fudging up my proxied request, and I haven't found a way to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have seen something similar when proxing requests to a different domain. The work around that I used was to modify the host header on the proxy request to match the domain name the remote site expects. So in your case the code would look like:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');


var server = httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
  req.headers.host = 'myapp.heroku.com';
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    port: 80,
    host: 'myapp.heroku.com'
  });
}).listen(9000);
```

I'd be interested to know if this works for you.

Comment: It works flawlessly. Setting the host in the header fixed it. For some reason I thought http-proxy would've done that. Thanks for saving me from using a dirty cURL hack!! Thanks!

Comment: http-proxy supports a changeOrigin option that takes care of this. https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#http-proxy

Comment: I literally discovered and did the exact same thing.