# nodejs proxy not responding

Tags: node.js, proxy

I have a node.js app that serve static files (html, js, css). Among the static files, some ajax request are done (with /TEST in the request). I need those request to be proxied to another server running on localhost:213445. The static pages are correctly displayed but when it comes to proxied request it hangs forever...

My code is:

```
var express = require("express");
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var fs = require('fs');

// Create https server
var app = express.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
});

// Handle static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Proxy request
app.all('/TEST/*',function(req, res){
  // Remove '/TEST' part from query string
  req.url = '/' + req.url.split('/').slice(2).join('/');

  // Create proxy
  var proxy = new httpProxy.HttpProxy();
  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 21345,
     enableXForwarded: false,
     buffer: proxy.buffer(req)
  });
});

// Run application
app.listen(10443);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue. If you comment out the

```
// Handle static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

you will see that the the proxy works.

Not sure how to fix it if express.static is used

Marak Squires responded to the bug [report](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/153)!

> This is an express problem.
>   The Connect / Express middlewares are doing non-standard things to your response object, 
>   breaks streaming. Try using the raw `request` module instead of `http-proxy`.
>   If you need proper middleware stack, check out https://github.com/flatiron/union

Comment: In fact, after some though, I decided to do the other way round. If static files are requested, Nginx will serve them. If some dynamic files are requested then Nginx proxy them to my node.js app. I though it was more Nginx job to serve static files.

Comment: Having the same problem and using the same solution right now. Still annoying that using static breaks the proxy code

Answer (score 2):

As described on the http-proxy [issue 180](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/180) the trouble is related to the non-standard things done by connect mentioned above:

Use npm to install connect-restreamer and make this the final item in your app.configuration of express:

```
app.use(require('connect-restreamer')());
```

Then do something like:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var routingProxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();

app.get('/proxy/', function (req, res) {
  routingProxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    target: {
       host : host,
       port : port
    }
  });
})
```

This will pass the whole URL, including "/proxy/" to the target host. You can [rewrite/modify the headers of the req](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444280/heroku-no-such-app-error-with-node-js-node-http-proxy-module) before they go into the `proxyRequest()` if you, e.g. want to mimic the request coming from a specific CNAME virtual host or different URL string.